# Building numpy with ATLAS/LAPACK support

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, lapack, atlas

I am trying to compile `numpy` v1.12 in order to get support for ATLAS/LAPACK routines.

**The problem**

The settings I am using for compilation do not appear to work in bringing ATLAS/LAPACK libraries into `numpy`.

**The setup**

I do not have admin privileges on the host(s) I am working on (a computational cluster).

However, the nodes offer access to `gcc` 4.7.2 and 5.3.0, `glibc` 2.17 and 2.22, and ATLAS/LAPACK libraries and headers v3.10.2 via GNU modules.

For compatibility reasons, I am working with a virtual environment that contains Python 2.7.16. Likewise, I am installing an older version of `numpy` for the same reason. If things work, I may explore newer versions of `numpy` but at this time, that is what I am working with.

My source directory for `numpy` has a configuration file called `site.cfg`, which includes these directives:

```
[ALL]
library_dirs = /usr/local/lib:/net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/lib64:/net/module/sw/atlas-lapack/3.10.2/lib
include_dirs = /usr/local/include:/net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/include:/net/module/sw/atlas-lapack/3.10.2/include

[atlas]
libraries = lapack,f77blas,cblas,atlas
library_dirs = /net/module/sw/atlas-lapack/3.10.2/lib
include_dirs = /net/module/sw/atlas-lapack/3.10.2/include
```

I am compiling `numpy` via the following command:

```
$ CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -std=c99 -fPIC" LDFLAGS="-L/home/areynolds/.conda/envs/genotyping_environment/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/areynolds/.conda/envs/genotyping_environment/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/,-L/net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/lib64" python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95
```

I am using `--fcompiler=gnu95` as the ATLAS/LAPACK libraries were compiled with GNU Fortran. I am overriding `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables in order for the GCC toolkit to be able to compile and link properly.

**The question**

After compilation, I test the `numpy` library to see what is installed via one method:

```
$ python
...
>>> import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo
>>> sysinfo.get_info('atlas')
ATLAS version 3.10.2 built by root on Wed Jun  1 15:39:08 PDT 2016:
    UNAME    : Linux module0.altiusinstitute.org 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    INSTFLG  : -1 0 -a 1 -l 1
    ARCHDEFS : -DATL_OS_Linux -DATL_ARCH_UNKNOWNx86 -DATL_CPUMHZ=2876 -DATL_AVXMAC -DATL_AVX -DATL_SSE3 -DATL_SSE2 -DATL_SSE1 -DATL_USE64BITS -DATL_GAS_x8664
    F2CDEFS  : -DAdd_ -DF77_INTEGER=int -DStringSunStyle
    CACHEEDGE: 229376
    F77      : /net/module/sw/gcc/5.3.0/bin/gfortran, version GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.3.0
    F77FLAGS : -O -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -fPIC
    SMC      : /usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc, version x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
    SMCFLAGS : -O -fomit-frame-pointer -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -fPIC
    SKC      : /usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc, version x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
    SKCFLAGS : -O -fomit-frame-pointer -mavx2 -mfma -m64 -fPIC                                                                                                                                                    
    {'libraries': ['lapack', 'f77blas', 'cblas', 'atlas', 'f77blas', 'cblas'], 'library_dirs': ['/net/module/sw/atlas-lapack/3.10.2/lib'], 'define_macros': [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.10.2\\""')], 'language': 'f77', 'include_dirs': ['/net/module/sw/atlas-lapack/3.10.2/include']}
```

This looks okay, maybe?

But when I check via another method, I get a different answer:

```
>>> np.show_config()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Despite the manual setup described in `site.cfg`, there are no mentions of ATLAS, nor is LAPACK apparently pointed to the correct module directory (`/net/module/sw/atlas-lapack/3.10.2`).

How do I correctly compile support for ATLAS/LAPACK into `numpy`, or truly test that I have a working ATLAS/LAPACK setup integrated into `numpy`, which gives me a consistent (and reliable) answer?

Comment: Could you link the log of the compilation process? Had you had your ATLAS module active during compilation?

Comment: Probably a stupid aside question/comment, but have you considered using anaconda here? I _think_ that should allow atlas without admin privilege. Anyway, your question is good in itself.

Comment: I have the ATLAS/LAPACK module loaded during compilation and I am using Anaconda as a module. ATLAS appears to be a separate installation from Anaconda and Python (and indeed it requires a separate GNU kit installed and available in order to build, which for my host took about 36 hours to finish optimization, before I could proceed with the rest of the Python setup).

Comment: @AlexReynolds, can you confirm if the atlas related code works or not? Is this a problem where you identifying if the module is present or not is required? Or is it that your numpy + atlas related code doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a test bench that would exhaustively check ATLAS/LAPACK routines. I have to rely on documentation and runtime checks of build parameters (which so far are contradictory or at least inconclusive). Mainly, I want to build an environment I can confidently hand off to another person and say, "Hey, this supports XYZ."

Answer (score 1):

An orthogonal suggestion, but it may be helpful in general, not just for your particular problem.

Give a look at [Spack](https://spack.io/).
It is a package manager that builds packages from sources. It is a very interesting and promising project which allows you to build a vast variety of libraries/software with just a few steps.

I've just checked and `py-numpy` is a supported package (i.e. `spack list numpy`). If you want to install with default options (check them with `spack info py-numpy`), you can just install it with a simple `spack install py-numpy` and it will be built along with missig dependencies.

If you want to change something, e.g. you may want to use a particular implementation or version of BLAS/LAPACK, you can easily specify the wanted dependency (i.e. `spack install py-numpy ^openblas`)

I can assure you it will save you a lot of headaches, it did for me a lot of times. I use it both on the HPC I work on and on my local machines.

I've just shown you a few commands, but I just scraped the surface of what you can easily do with it (you may have multiple variant of numpy built with different BLAS implementations, or same implementation with different options, or ... in case I suggest you to start looking at ["spec syntax"](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html#specs-dependencies)).

Answer (score 0):

BLAS/LAPACK is an optional dependency for numpy. So, depending on what you are trying to do, you might leave ATLAS out completely.

If you want to make sure that your numpy was compiled against the correct libraries, I would go outside of Python and numpy and use `ldd` on the compiled libraries.

I'm on latest numpy and Python 3.7, so filenames will look different for you.

```
> cd <numpy_dir>
> find . -name "*.so"

./core/_dummy.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./core/_operand_flag_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./core/_rational_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./core/_struct_ufunc_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./core/_umath_tests.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./fft/fftpack_lite.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-37m-darwin.so
./random/mtrand.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Then I ran `ldd` (I used `otool -L` since I'm on macOS) on each file. The following 3 files were compiled against the BLAS library.

```
core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-darwin.so
linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Comment: This approach suggests that the `linalg` libraries were linked to `libmkl_rt.so` (Intel MKL), which doesn't seem to agree with either of the two Python approaches I use above. Maybe I can't trust what numpy or Python says?

Comment: Looking at the source (v1.12) at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.12.x/numpy/distutils/system_info.py it seems that `lapack_opt_info()` (l. 1467) looks for libraries in a particular order. If MKL is present, it is used first, then openblas, then atlas. This is what's used to determine available blas libraries at compile time. `show_config()` on the other hand, shows the contents of `__config__.py` which is generated during build.

Comment: Try building without site.cfg, but instead use `BLAS=<path_to_atlas> LAPACK=<path_to_atlas> ATLAS=<path_to_atlas> OPENBLAS=None MKL_ROOT=None` on the command line when running `python setup`.

Comment: Recompiling with these additional options did not change the result of my tests. Interestingly, `ldd` is now telling me that the `so` files are not dynamic executables. When I run `file` on them, I get back the description: `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked`.

Comment: Interesting side note: numpy 1.17 just came out and one of the improvements is a new variable `NPY_BLAS_ORDER` to set the BLAS detection order. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#user-defined-blas-detection-order

Answer (score 0):

I did it with numpy 1.11.1 (which means that my answer may not be 100% accurate in your case) with the following receipe:

```
export ATLAS=<folder with the atlas/lapack libraries>
export LAPACK=$ATLAS
cat > site.cfg <<EOF
[atlas]
atlas_libs = lapack, f77blas, cblas, atlas
EOF
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you can get the numpy source onto the machine, I would assume you can get any files you like into your user space. Have you considered installing numpy from a wheel?

Numpy 1.16.4 has support for Python 2.7. You haven't said what architecture your nodes are, but I would be a bit surprised if there isn't a wheel available. You should be able to download it directly from PyPi yourself:

https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.16.4/#files

Once you've downloaded the wheel file and transferred it, assuming you've already installed `pip`, etc., you can install it:

`pip install --no-index --user (file).whl`

Also, I would be reluctant about saying that ATLAS/LAPACK is the best option. It has been benchmarked here, and it looks like OpenBLAS is just fine: https://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html.